# Quick directory navigation when opening/saving in Emacs?

Tags: emacs

In many text editors, when I want to open or save a file, a GUI dialog pops up that lets me navigate to the desired folder, and pick the file to open or save to.

As I try to learn Emacs 24 on Mac OS X 10.6.8, the only way I know of opening or saving files is by entering the appropriate shortcut (i.e. "C-x-C" to save, "C-x-C-f" to open), followed by the *complete path* to the target directory. When I create a new file in a new folder this way, I also have to enter the command "M-x make-directory RET RET" to creat the folder.

Is there a quicker way to do all of the above, especially the part where I have to enter the full path to a file?

Thanks!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`ido-mode`](http://emacswiki.org/emacs/InteractivelyDoThings) is one way.  It rebinds `C-x C-f` to `ido-find-file`.  `ido-find-file` does not provide a GUI file dialog, but it does completion, which you may find preferable.  It also provides completion for other operations, such as `ido-switch-buffer`

I find that, in addition to the basics, `C-j` and `C-f` are quite important to know when using ido.

`ido-mode` can be used in conjuction with [`dired`](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Dired.html).  You can use `+` to create a directory in `dired-mode`.  When using ido, you can use `C-j` to enter dired.  When using dired, you can use `C-x C-f` to enter ido.

Comment: Just to note that C-j in one sense does two different things in ido: If the path ends in a "/", then it jumps into dired.  Otherwise, it jumps to a non-dired buffer visiting the path.  The latter is useful to avoid unwanted completions when creating a file.

Answer (score 1):

On my machine, using File->Open shows a GUI dialog (but this may be platform- and build-dependent).  [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/391589/720877) explains how to make C-x C-f use the GUI file dialog too.

Answer (score 1):

Emacs is very customizable and lots of people have written various packages to make file opening easier. See this page for packages to open files from anywhere [regardless of their location](http://emacswiki.org/emacs/LocateFilesAnywhere).